# how to set preference summary without the deprecated method findPreference for android 4.0 +

Tags: android, deprecated, summary

i want to set a preference summary , usually it can be done with

```
    EditTextPreference Pref = (EditTextPreference) findPreference(key);

    Pref.setSummary("new summary");
```

but since Android 4.1, findPreference throws an NPE (?), is there any other method to set the summary of a preference in preferenceHeaders/preferenceFragment ? (but not with xml, i need the summary value to be dynamic)

Comment: problem solved, the deprecated method findPreference() was not the problem, i called findPreference() before addPreferencesFromResource() in the preferenceFragment and that was the problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is elsewhere. `findPreference()` may be deprecated, but it is still available for use in the API -- it just isn't relevant if you're using Fragments.

See the Android 4.2 source for [`PreferenceActivity`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.java#PreferenceActivity.findPreference%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) that shows the method clearly still available.

I use it for all preferences in my application, and have no issues even on 4.2.2.

If you're using `PreferenceFragments`, be aware that you should use the [`findPreference()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html#findPreference%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method on your `PreferenceFragment` instance rather than from a `PreferenceActivity`.

See [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) for more information.

Comment: thanks a lot , I'll look into it and determine the npe problem.

Comment: turns out my code was calling findPreference(key) before addPreferencesFromResource() in the fragment, thanks a lot kcoppock :)